# Prevent local duplicates with the External Database Authentication Plugin on Moodle

Tags: php, authentication, plugins, remote-access, moodle

I'm using Moodle's external database plugin and am having a very annoying problem. Here's an example:

**username:** johndoe@gmail.com logs in with his password and both are saved in an external DB. Moodle grabs that data (username, password) and saves it locally (mysql) with that user's external DB id. Keep in mind the external DB is the main DB where everything happens, Moodle is only for authorized users that need to take tests. So in Moodle, I have:

username: johndoe@gmail.com
password: blabla
userid: 1234

It works great, **except** for when johndoe@gmail.com decides to update his username/email on the external DB, so he wants it to be johndoe@hotmail.com now. When he tries to log in, it logs in fine, since Moodle checks with the external DB for both username/password. **Problem:** A new record is created within Moodle for johndoe@hotmail.com with same password **AND** userid.

**My question is:** Where can I safely check with the local DB if userid already exists and **NOT** create a new record? I do not want to update the moodlelib doc because I don't want to have upgrading problems in the future. I can update the External DB plugin, but can't figure out where would be best.

Here's a workaround someone did - https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=232163 - but it's done in a cron job instead of immediately on Login.

**UPDATE:**
It looks like I'll have to update moodlelib and the external db plugin, I'll post my solution if nobody posts.

Comment: What about updating the user in Moodle with a call to `core_user_update_users` web service when your user decide to update his username on the external db?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Where would that call be? And when?

Comment: The user reach the web page to change his username at you script `change.php`. He `POST`s the new values to your application... then, your script validates them, and call the Moodle web service. If all went ok, it also updates them in your external DB.

Comment: That could work if the process would be done in one application only... unfortunately we have a separate tool that can be used to update the email and it's a windows software which we can't update...thanks for the idea though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody replied, this is the best I could come up with. I have my own comments with *UPDATED so you know where I updated the code.

Under **\moodle\lib\moodlelib.php**
*(Unfortunately I had to update this file because of an authentication call that would trigger the duplicate creation)*.

1) Update function authenticate_user_login(); replace line 4342 - 4382 with:

```
$authsenabled = get_enabled_auth_plugins();

// *UPDATED - begin
$authplugin = get_auth_plugin('DB');
$userinfo = ($authplugin->get_userinfo($username)) ? $authplugin->get_userinfo($username) : 0;
// *UPDATED - end    

// *UPDATED - added second elseif
if ($user = get_complete_user_data('username', $username, $CFG->mnet_localhost_id)) {    
    // Use manual if auth not set.
    $auth = empty($user->auth) ? 'manual' : $user->auth;
    if (!empty($user->suspended)) {
        add_to_log(SITEID, 'login', 'error', 'index.php', $username);
        error_log('[client '.getremoteaddr()."]  $CFG->wwwroot  Suspended Login:  $username  ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $failurereason = AUTH_LOGIN_SUSPENDED;
        return false;
    }
    if ($auth=='nologin' or !is_enabled_auth($auth)) {
        add_to_log(SITEID, 'login', 'error', 'index.php', $username);
        error_log('[client '.getremoteaddr()."]  $CFG->wwwroot  Disabled Login:  $username  ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        // Legacy way to suspend user.
        $failurereason = AUTH_LOGIN_SUSPENDED;
        return false;
    }
    $auths = array($auth);

} 
elseif ($user = get_complete_user_data('idnumber', $userinfo['idnumber'], $CFG->mnet_localhost_id)) {
    $auth = empty($user->auth) ? 'manual' : $user->auth;  // use manual if auth not set
    if (!empty($user->suspended)) {
        add_to_log(SITEID, 'login', 'error', 'index.php', $username);
        error_log('[client '.getremoteaddr()."]  $CFG->wwwroot  Suspended Login:  $username  ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $failurereason = AUTH_LOGIN_SUSPENDED;
        return false;
    }
    if ($auth=='nologin' or !is_enabled_auth($auth)) {
        add_to_log(SITEID, 'login', 'error', 'index.php', $username);
        error_log('[client '.getremoteaddr()."]  $CFG->wwwroot  Disabled Login:  $username  ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $failurereason = AUTH_LOGIN_SUSPENDED; // Legacy way to suspend user.
        return false;
    }
    $auths = array($auth);    
}    
else {
    // Check if there's a deleted record (cheaply), this should not happen because we mangle usernames in delete_user().
    if ($DB->get_field('user', 'id', array('username' => $username, 'mnethostid' => $CFG->mnet_localhost_id,  'deleted' => 1))) {
        error_log('[client '.getremoteaddr()."]  $CFG->wwwroot  Deleted Login:  $username  ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $failurereason = AUTH_LOGIN_NOUSER;
        return false;
    }

    // Do not try to authenticate non-existent accounts when user creation is not disabled.
    if (!empty($CFG->authpreventaccountcreation)) {
        add_to_log(SITEID, 'login', 'error', 'index.php', $username);
        error_log('[client '.getremoteaddr()."]  $CFG->wwwroot  Unknown user, can not create new accounts:  $username  ".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $failurereason = AUTH_LOGIN_NOUSER;
        return false;
    }

    // User does not exist.
    $auths = $authsenabled;
    $user = new stdClass();
    $user->id = 0;
}
```

2) Same function, replace line 4408 - 4427 with:

```
if ($user->id) {
    // User already exists in database.
    if (empty($user->auth)) {
        // For some reason auth isn't set yet.
        // *UPDATED $DB->set_field('user', 'auth', $auth, array('username'=>$username));
        $DB->set_field('user', 'auth', $auth, array('idnumber'=>$user->idnumber));                
        $user->auth = $auth;
    }

    // If the existing hash is using an out-of-date algorithm (or the legacy md5 algorithm), then we should update to
    // the current hash algorithm while we have access to the user's password.
    update_internal_user_password($user, $password);

    if ($authplugin->is_synchronised_with_external()) {
        // Update user record from external DB.
        // *UPDATED $user = update_user_record($username);
        $user = $authplugin->update_user_record($username, $user->idnumber);                
    }
} else {
    // Create account, we verified above that user creation is allowed.
    $user = create_user_record($username, $password, $auth);
}
```

Under **\moodle\auth\db\auth.php** *(External DB plugin Lib)*

1) Update function update_user_record() to receive the IDNUMBER parameter:

```
function update_user_record($username, $idnumber='', $updatekeys=false) {
```

2) Replace line 512 with:

```
$user = $DB->get_record('user', array('idnumber'=>$idnumber, 'mnethostid'=>$CFG->mnet_localhost_id));
```

So now, the main function under the moodle lib will check if user exists by username, if not, checks if user ID exists...if so, it will update the user's info with the new info coming from the external DB. It works fine on Moodle 2.4 and 2.6 for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old answer, but there's an alternative that requires no manual patching.

The OP uses email addresses (instead of arbitrary usernames) to identify users. This behaviour can be maintained by setting Site administration > Plugins > Authentication > Manage authentication > Allow log in via email (`authloginviaemail`) to true. Now the username can be populated by the (stable) external database ID. Changing email addresses hence won't result in new accounts.